# ExtJS: MultiSelect Combo in an EditorGrid

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, multi-select, extjs3

There are some nice ComboBoxes for forms (f.e. the [LovCombo](http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/) or the [SuperBoxSelect](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?69090-Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect-as-seen-on-facebook-and-hotmail)).

I got a ComboBox working in a Grid. But how do I include a **MultiSelect** ComboBox in an Editor Grid? What is the best approach? Is there any existing code to get started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the defined `xtypes` that the controls provide? If you look at the LovCombo for example, you'll see:

```
Ext.reg('lovcombo', Ext.ux.form.LovCombo);
```

Inside of your Grid, for each column, define the editor:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'lovcombo'
    ...
}
```